# how do we update an already existing iam policy with a new json file using aws cli commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How do we update an already existing iam policy with a new json file using aws cli commands?

I already have a policy named mypolicy. I want to update this policy with a new json file (which has access to different resources). How do I perform this using aws cli command?

I tried to find the cli command. I found the command below from an AWS page:

```
aws organizations update-policy \
    --policy-id p-examplepolicyid111 \
    --content "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}}"
```

However, with this command I did not find any way to replace the policy with new json.

Answer (score 7):

#### create policy version.

```
aws iam create-policy-version 
 --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MyPolicy 
 --policy-document file://NewPolicyVersion.json --set-as-default
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-policy-version.html

#### list policies managed by customer

```
aws iam list-policies --scope Local
```

#### get a policy by arn

```
aws iam get-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MyPolicy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it worked. i have one more query. how do we get the policy arn number with the policyname

Comment: Do you want to get the policy ARN using its name ? I can't think of a direct way. I would try to get the list of policies and see if one of the policy name matches the value.

Comment: You may have to run `list-policies`, iterate the results and run `get-policy` on each. Then you match the name to find the policy you are looking for. as a i said, not a direct method.

Comment: @padmasree perhaps you can mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 4 policies you will not be able to run the aws iam create-policy-version command. To account for this in one script you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

POLICY_ARN='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:policy/my-policy'

if [ "$(aws iam list-policy-versions --policy-arn ${POLICY_ARN} | jq -r '.Versions[].VersionId' | wc -l)" -gt 4 ]; then
    OLDEST_VERSION=$(aws iam list-policy-versions --policy-arn ${POLICY_ARN} | \
      jq -r '.Versions |= sort_by(.CreateDate) | .Versions[0].VersionId')
    echo "You have more than 4 versions of ${POLICY_ARN}."
    echo "Deleting oldest version: ${OLDEST_VERSION}"
    aws iam delete-policy-version --policy-arn ${POLICY_ARN} \
       --version-id "${OLDEST_VERSION}"
fi

aws iam create-policy-version --policy-arn ${POLICY_ARN} \
   --policy-document file://new-policy.json --set-as-default
```

This will delete the oldest version and then create a new version using the policy found in the local file new-policy.json. This file must already exist before you run the above command.

Comment: Blessings upon your house, and every kitten therein.